# Unicode in java to call

Tags: java, android, unicode, urlencode, phone-number

Here below is a sample of my code, so what i am trying to do is to place a call using the number below. when i run the application it shows me sent, then after it places a call to *155 instead of *155#.

Thanks in advance.

```
String tel = "tel:" + '\u002A' + 155 + '\u0023';
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(tel));
startActivity(callIntent);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
"sent " + tel, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `'\u0023'` with `"%23"`. Hashtag is a reserved character and therefore you have to passed in  '%'-escaped octets using the UTF-8 scheme.

See 
[RFC 2396 - Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396.html) for details.

Alternatively you can use the static method of Uri:

```
Uri.encode("*155#");
```

and it will do the escaping for you.